# Как сделать чтобы при нажатии клавиши стрелки (вправо) с клавиатуры срабатывал тег a?

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <li><a href="{page-next}" class="next_page testss"></a></li>
```

Вот код для переключения, он работает если нажимать на него мышкой. Как сделать так, чтобы если нажму кнопку с клавиатуры, я мог бы получить тот же результат, что от клика мышкой?

Comment: Конечно работает, это ссылка. А вот клавиатуру нужно слушать. А как слушать! Слушателями.  Это асинхронная операция, которая ждёт выполнения функции при  event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повешать обработчик события keydown и в нем вызвать метод .click() у элемента a.

```
const a = document.querySelector(".next_page");
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.key == "ArrowRight") {    
        a.click();
    } 
});
```

Также переход по урлу можно сделать без имитации клика по элементу:

```
location.href = URL;
```

Comment: При 1 нажатии все работает, при 2 страница обновляется, при 3 опять работает, 4 обновляет и т.д. как это исправить?

Comment: @ZAKATTACK по такому описанию проблемы мне сложно что-либо подсказать.