# Почему переключение страницы клавишей клавиатуры срабатывает неправильно?

Tags: javascript

Ранее задавал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1343459/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d1%82) по поводу переключения, мне помогли. Но проблема в том, что переключение работает не совсем корректно. При нажатии на клавишу первый раз переключение работает, на второй раз страница обновляется. Третий работает, четвертый обновляет и т.д. Само переключение работает через AJAX. Как это исправить?

Comment: у вас это единственная ссылка с классом `,next_page` на странице?

Comment: Да, только что перепроверил. Единственная. 

Может проще будет посмотреть, ссылка на саму страницу https://gitmanga.com/read-48-ataka-titanov.html?t=1&g=2&p=11 (переключение страницы вперед, на клавиатуре стрелка вправо)

Comment: если в отладчике поставите брейк на событие нажатия кнопки, то заметите, что там в целом при втором нажатии туда не передается управление.

Comment: Есть варианты почему это происходит и как решить?